# PHP Imagick - Unable to read image from the filehandle [XAMPP on Win10 x64]

Tags: php, xampp, imagemagick, imagick, filehandle

I'm facing the following problem with this simple chunk of code:

```
$picstream = fopen($url, 'rb');
$picture = new Imagick();
try {
    $picture->readImageFile($picstream);
}
catch (ImagickExpection $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The `$url` variable is a public, accessible URL which points to a JPEG picture.

Then I get the following error: "*Unable to read image from the filehandle*".

The weird thing is that if I do a `stream_get_contents($picstream)` and then `echo` it with the `Content-Type: image/jpeg` headers, I'm able to see the image, so `fopen` returns a valid resource.

Local server has installed:

- Apache 2.4.4
- PHP 5.6.14 (VC11) 32bit TS
- ImageMagick-6.8.6-8-Q16-x86-dll
- php_imagick-3.1.2-5.6-ts-vc11-x86
- Windows 10 x64

Also, it's weird as well that in a Linux box (Debian Jessie), I can open URLs directly from the `Imagick` constructor, as well as reading the stream this way, but I haven't been able to do so under Windows & XAMPP. I don't have any clue why is this happening, therefore can't think of a solution better than the `file_put_contents` workaround.

Any ideas? Some misconfig I'm missing?

Comment: Just use the work around of downloading the file first and then opening it locally. Reading an image directly from an open connection in ImageMagick is just flaky as heck.

Comment: Why not `new Imagick($url)`? But @Danack is right, you should get the file locally (plus validate & error-handle) before attempting to load resource into memory.

Comment: `new Imagick($url)` prompts a "Cannot read file" error on Win & XAMPP, even though it works on a LAMP stack.